# How do I place two tables with headings next to each other Using CSS

Tags: html, css

```
    <h1 class="floor">Floor Scale</h1>
    <table>
      <thead>
          <th>Size</th>
          <th>Capacity</th>
          <th>Color</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>4' x 4'</td>
          <td>5000 lbs</td>
          <td>Blue</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4' x 4'</td>
          <td>10,000 lbs</td>
          <td>Black</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>

    <h1 class="balance">Balance Scales</h1>
    <table>
      <thead>
          <th>Size</th>
          <th>Capacity</th>
          <th>Color</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1' x 1'</td>
          <td>5,000g</td>
          <td>White</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1' x 1'</td>
          <td>200,000g</td>
          <td>White</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

With the code above, they will be placed on top of each other instead of next to each other. What I am trying to do is place them next to each other. It would be great if you could specify how this can be done in both HTML and CSS.

Comment: I know this isn't an answer to your question, but if you can I'd recommended not building it this way and consider using CSS Grids. It's a lot more flexible and modern than old school tables. Worth a consideration and it will save you a lot of headache down the road.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap you table in a `div` and wrap those table in `container` and use `display:flex` to place headings and table next to each other.

Also, to make it nice and have a good space between them use `justify content space around`

You can read about flex boxes [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and using flex in CSS.

Run snippet below.

```css
.container {
      display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="table">
    <h1 class="floor">Floor Scale</h1>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <th>Size</th>
        <th>Capacity</th>
        <th>Color</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>4' x 4'</td>
          <td>5000 lbs</td>
          <td>Blue</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4' x 4'</td>
          <td>10,000 lbs</td>
          <td>Black</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="table">

    <h1 class="balance">Balance Scales</h1>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <th>Size</th>
        <th>Capacity</th>
        <th>Color</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1' x 1'</td>
          <td>5,000g</td>
          <td>White</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1' x 1'</td>
          <td>200,000g</td>
          <td>White</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Parham Glad to hear - Please consider accepting the answer as well by marking the check mark in the [asnwer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: I have another similar coding issue, which I will post in a few minutes. I would appreciate it if you could help me out on that as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to set width and inline display:

```
.row {
  width: 100%;
}

.column {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 49%;
}
```

```
<div class="row">
<div class="column">
    <h1 class="floor">Floor Scale</h1>
    <table>
      <thead>
          <th>Size</th>
          <th>Capacity</th>
          <th>Color</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>4' x 4'</td>
          <td>5000 lbs</td>
          <td>Blue</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4' x 4'</td>
          <td>10,000 lbs</td>
          <td>Black</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
     </table>
    </div>
    
    <div class="column">
     <h1 class="balance">Balance Scales</h1>
    <table>
      <thead>
          <th>Size</th>
          <th>Capacity</th>
          <th>Color</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1' x 1'</td>
          <td>5,000g</td>
          <td>White</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1' x 1'</td>
          <td>200,000g</td>
          <td>White</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
</div>
```